# VSCode: How to prevent window resize when maximized (Windows)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've noticed that when I have VSCode maximized (note: NOT full screen), there's still the resize area at the bottom of the screen near the taskbar. I keep accidentally hitting the resize zone instead of my quick launch icons, etc. It can be very frustrating because sometimes, after a few misclicks, the window ends up covering part of my task bar. Is there any way to prevent that resize zone from being active? The ones on the top and sides of the window are not active while maximized, and other apps like my browser do not have this behavior.

[problem demo desktop recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMwAF.gif)

I have tried flipping some of the settings in the Window group of preferences, but nothing seemed to affect this behavior.

Comment: 1) does this happen for other apps? does it happen for all your chromium-based apps? In either of those cases, the problem would have nothing to do with VS Code. 2) I cannot reproduce this issue on my Windows 11 machine with VS Code installed at the system level. What OS do you have and what version of it, and did you do a user or system install of VS Code?

Comment: I could have sworn both my work and personal computers (Win 10) were affected, but it turns out my work computer actually isn't. (guess you only notice stuff when it's actively bugging you lol?) You're right about the Chromium app thing - I'd never noticed because I don't use it maximized, but on that computer, Discord is also affected. Gives me a good place to start looking, thanks!

Comment: Update: It's... fixed? I have no clue what I did to "fix" it. It may have had something to do with my taskbar, which was unlocked, but I swear I tried that last night and it didn't help. Not loving that I don't know what was wrong or what fixed it, but I am loving being able to click my quicklaunch easily again. Thanks for the comment, user!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed accidentally.

It turns out that it was only affecting a single computer, and other Chromium apps were also affected (ex: Discord) (thanks commenter!)

It stopped happening after I launched Edge to check whether it was affected, noticed my taskbar was unlocked, and locked it. But the behavior shown in my video is not the expected taskbar unlocked behavior, so I'm still unsure how that's related, or whether or not it's what fixed it.

(I was doing seemingly unrelated things at the time, like searching the registry and app data, and fighting Defender to let me extract my Windows key in case I decided to go for the overkill approach and reinstall)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).